# Regex in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe like this a column like this

```
COL1      
RED[10%(INC)]
RED[12%(INC)]
```

and I want create `col2` as this

```
COL2
10
12
```

Could cou help me to find the good regex?
I tried this:

```
RED\[(\d+\.\d+) %INC\]
```

but it doesn't walk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your regex and only extract numbers in the specified context, you can use

```py
df['COL2'] = df['COL1'].str.extract(r'RED\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%\[INC]]', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ1FMH/1).

**Details**

- `RED\[`  - a `RED[` string
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `%\[INC]]` - a `%[INC]]` literal string.

You could also explore other options:

- Extracting the number followed with a percentage sign: `df['COL1'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%', expand=False)`
- Splitting with `[`, getting the second item and removing `%` from it: `df['COL1'].str.split("[").str[1].str.replace("%", "")`

Comment: Hi !! thank you verymuch,  and If I have something like this RED[12%(/INC)] (with a /)

Comment: @T.mum Did you check the "other options"? If you have `(` and `)`, escpae them. `/` is not necessary to escape.

Comment: @viktor I tried `RED\[(\d+\.\d+) %\(\/INC\)\]` but it's doesn't walk, I don't know how I can handle the / before INC

Comment: @T.mum there is no space in your input, why do you add space to the pattern? Why don't you make decimal part optional the way I showed in my answer? Please reread the regex explanation. Use `RED\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%\(/INC\)]`. In Python strings, you do not need to escape slashes, they are not any special regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `re.findall`:

Modules and data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':['RED[10%(INC)','RED[12%(INC)']})
```

Solution:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('[0-9]+', x))
df['COL2'] = pd.DataFrame(df['COL2'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['COL2']= np.where(df['COL1'].str.extract(r'RED\[(d+)')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please review the accepted answer for a good demonstration of the level of explanation that’s useful for answers.